# Synchronize data between two SQL Server 2008 databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I'm working on a project in C# .BET 3.5 with 2 SQL Server 2008 R2 databases. I need to update new/changed data from local db to online db. Client system has low bandwidth connection. So I need a solution to upload a file to sync.

Can anyone tell me how I can do this? Programming example will be more beneficial for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [ADO.NET Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753) - it's designed to handle such a scenario and probably is the easiest approach to do this (helps you get things done quickly, without writing too much code yourself)

To get started, read [Introduction to Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992) and then [Introduction to Sync Framework Database Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608)

Comment: thanks for answering.can you give me C# example? because i have very short time.

Comment: @anjum habib: see [this RSS feed with a **TON** of samples](http://services.community.microsoft.com/feeds/feed/syncdemo)

Comment: I need samples or example of two database sync